# Loading a hyperlink opened in a div - in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

Following on my from my previous question here:
[How to show a page by default on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628699/how-to-show-a-page-by-default-on-page-load)

I'm basically using jQuery to load links in a div - this works perfectly. However, what I want to now achieve, is when one of the pages (opened in the div) has a hyperlink, how can I open the hyperlink in the same div the page sits in now?

Let's say I have a menu: 
Home | Service | About

If you click service  - it loads the page inside a div - awesome.

But let's say service has a hyperlink to another page (on the same domain/setup) - currently using my code referenced in the question above, the link just opens in a new tab... This isn't the behaviour I want.

Here is the code:

```
  $('[data-target]').click( function (e) {
$.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){ 
 $('#halloffame').empty(); 
  $(data).find(".partner_body").appendTo("#halloffame");

});
e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor from changing window.location
  }); 
  $.get( "pages/accounting-software/", function( data ) { 
       $('#halloffame').empty(); 
        $(data).find(".partner_body").appendTo("#halloffame");

   });
```

This lets me open hyper links in the div "halloffame". But it doesn't control the links in the pages - even if I use the same code on the master page:

```
<a data-target="#halloffame" href="pages/returns/">
```

If anyone can point me to where I'm going wrong, I would appreciate it :)

Have an awesome Friday, folks!

Comment: did you try target="_self" in your anchor tag? <a data-target="#halloffame" href="pages/returns/" target="_self">

Comment: @riteshmeher - thanks, good shout, I hadn't but have just tried it and no joy :( >>> Code in full >>>>> https://gyazo.com/ca5fb1087b26d1f8cb54f6f6f0f5dc52

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener is bound the the *currently* existing DOM, when you add new elements(from your ajax call) you need to either bind your event listener to the new elements aswell or use deferred event handling(eg [jQuerys `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

[See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414695/attaching-events-after-dom-manipulation-using-jquery-ajax)